# Argument of \mathaccentV has an extra }

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am not able to locate the source of this error.

```
! Argument of \mathaccentV has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.238
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
```

Latex tells me that it is in **line 238**, **but what I have in line 238 is the following text:**

> When we have a simulated cluster catalogue, we are given with
>   cosmological and spectroscopic redshifts. Distances

When there are no mathematical symbols or equations, how do I find out where the extra `}` is missing?

**Why is Latex pointing in the wrong line?**

**EDIT:**

I tried commenting section by section, but the error remained. Then **I commented the entire file,** but still when I compile, I get this error!! What is this sorcery? **How can it throw an error when I have commented the entire document?**

LOG FILE:

I have uploaded the `.log` file [HERE](http://www.filedropper.com/thesis), please can someone help me out??

The error appears in `line 1703` of the `.log` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To locate the error look in the log for a `(` without a matching `)` before the error, In this case

```
(./Thesis.bbl
```

So the error is on line 238 of the generated bibliography

So, delete Thesis.bbl, fix the corresponding entry in the bib file and re-run latex and bibtex to re-generate.